# Take sha number of commit by tig

Tags: git, sha, tig

I love to use [tig](https://jonas.github.io/tig/) client to navigate through git commits.

But I'm missing one thing for now.

Is there a key binding to take a sha number of a git commit I'm currently staying at?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check if the command proposed in [`jonas/tig` issue 557](https://github.com/jonas/tig/issues/557) would work for you:

```
bind generic 9 !sh -c "echo -n %(commit) | xclip -selection c && echo Copied %(commit) to clipboard"
```

That would copy the [current commit SHA1](https://github.com/jonas/tig/blob/d75c51099cb0d7b3232d9037227ea22fc2e60283/tigrc#L161) in your clipboard.

In the [Wiki binding page](https://github.com/jonas/tig/wiki/Bindings), you also have example for Mac or Cygwin:

```
bind generic 9 !@sh -c "git show -s --format=%s %(commit) | xclip -selection c" # Linux
bind generic 9 !@sh -c "git show -s --format=%s %(commit) | pbcopy" # Mac
bind generic 9 !@sh -c "git show -s --format=%s %(commit) > /dev/clipboard" # Cygwin
```

The [OP megas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458137/megas) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542803/take-sha-number-of-commit-by-tig/52578478?noredirect=1#comment92115298_52578478) to use [`git rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse):

```
bind generic 9 !@sh -c "git rev-parse --short %(commit) | pbcopy"
```

Comment: I came up with this solution: `bind generic 9 !@sh -c "git rev-parse --short %(commit) | pbcopy"`

Comment: @megas OK, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

To copy the short SHA1 on **MacOS** (can be easily adapted to other OS):

```
bind generic 9 +@sh -c "printf '%s' $(git rev-parse --short %(commit)) | pbcopy && echo Copied %(commit) to clipboard"
```

As an improvement to other answers, this version prints out a message to the status bar which is nicer to closing the `tig` UI or having nothing printed out. The `+` option flag enables to do so ([source](https://github.com/jonas/tig/pull/678)). Also no extra newline character at the end like [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

### MacOS

```
bind generic 9 !@sh -c "printf '%s' %(commit) | pbcopy"
```

Or, to copy the short sha-1:

```
bind generic 9 !@sh -c "printf '%s' $(git rev-parse --short %(commit)) | pbcopy"
```

Inspiration source: [/tig/doc/tigrc(5) - Bind Command](https://jonas.github.io/tig/doc/tigrc.5.html#_bind_command) in the exemple section.

Solutions listed in [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)'s answer did not work for me because of a return line in the pasted result (⌘+V). So I was not able to type such command in tig `:!git rebase -i [paste_here_hitting_⌘+V]~`